# Sonar Plugin not showing up in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I installed the Sonar plugin(3.2) to eclipse  (juno). 
[link](http://dist.sonaride.codehaus.org/eclipse/). 
However i cannot find it in eclipse . Window > Preferences > does not show up the sonar option. I have restarted eclipse using clear flag (both in command line and modifying the .ini file) but it does not help.
 Is there anything else i can do to get the sonar option available?

Comment: Well un-install and install (n number of times) did the magic !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was some issue with the 3.2 version of sonar and Juno. An older version of Sonar (2.X) can easily be integrated with juno.

Comment: what about Juno and 3.5 sonar?